# Writting multiple files as byte array in an spring batch ETL csv Feed

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-batch, file-handling

We have a **authoring portal**, which is used to create/edit the **Notifications**. These Notifications are just like emails having sender, subject, content and attachments(can be any document of type pdf, doc, xls, png, jpg + 15 more types).Each notification can have multiple attachments and maximum size of a notification can be 15 MB. We save these notifications in MongoDB and Attachments in GridFS.

The Notifications created by this authoring tool, needs to be published to a different **web application** used by the end users. For publishing these Notifications to client application, we planned to create 2 Spring batch ETL's

1. **Export ETL**: Spring batch ETL that should read the Notification Authoring database and writes the notifications to a csv feed.
2. **Import ETL**: Should read the CSV feed generated by the Export ETL and import the notifications to client web application database.

My Question is,

> How should I export the attachment files of the notification by the
>   Export ETL?

Should we write a byte array of each attachment + metadata to the CSV feed along with the notification data. If yes, then do we need to worry about the any encoding/decoding/formatting issues of the files.

Can anyone please suggest any other approach, if writing the attachment files as byte array+metadata to CSV feed is not good enough.

I know the question seems to be long, please bear with me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any reason why you reinvent the wheel? Use either mail with limited attachment sizes or use AMQP or sth like that. Reinventing the wheel is neither technically nor monetarily feasible.

Comment: I agree with you Markus W Mahlberg  but the reason this complex approach is used is  because of the current architecture of the project. Our custom made notifications only suits our requirements.We have a series of validations and verification steps in between that needs to be performed before the notifications are approved and published.We have an api extending the spring-batch which helps us ease out our tasks for most of the other operations.....Still I appreciate your efforts to look into my problem and respond. Thanks.

Comment: Hm, still, use something like Camel and AMQP and just write the according filters/converters instead of redoing everything. Anything that stands against this? ;)